# can't open a page in a browser that is running in docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to open **localhost:8000** but it doesn't work.
When I type docker ps it says that's container is fine

Here's my

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn app:app
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My python entrypoint file

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    response_body = b'Hello, world'
    status = '200 OK'
    start_response(status, headers=[])
    return iter([response_body])
```

And entrypoint.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh

gunicorn app:app

exec "$@"
```

Structure of the project:

```
/venv
app.py
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
entrypoint.sh
requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/settings.html#server-socket), this is the default host:port gunicorn binds to:

**Server Socket**
default: ['127.0.0.1:8000']

I suggest starting gunicorn this way in your entrypoint:

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app`